# Python: add numbers based on preceding identifier in disorganized file

Tags: python-3.x

I have a mess of a file in this format:

```
a11      0.0
a12    132.0
b13      0.0
b42    584.0
randomstuff
etc
a11      0.0
a12      6.0
b13    138.0
b42      6.0
```

There are thousands of a##, b##, c##, etc combinations, but they repeat over and over again with some useless stuff in between. I want to add all the numbers for each item, so I just have:

```
a11, 0
a12, 138
b13, 138
b42, 590
```

I need some way to generate each identifier (a11, a12, etc) because there are thousands of different ones.

Comment: sounds like groupby is all you need

Comment: Do you also want to parse this input file, or just generate all the different combinations of [a-z][0-9][0-9] ?

Comment: @Kingsley I want to 1) get all the combinations of identifier, which is not every single combo of [a-z][0-9][0-9] and then 2) use those to sum up all the different values in my file for each of the identifiers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To generate all the combinations, a simple way to do this is just 3x loops:

```
for letter in 'abcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyz':
    for digit1 in '0123456789':
        for digit2 in '0123456789':
            print(letter + digit1 + digit2)
```

Which generates `a00` -> `z99`

But to parse this data, it's probably easier to just check your input line follows the format, and then tally it into a dictionary

```
code_sums = {}  # empty dictionary
lines = open("input_file.txt", "rt").readlines()
for row in lines:
    # check the line is good input
    # cleanup and single space
    row = row.strip().replace('\t', ' ')
    while (row.find('  ') != -1):
        row = row.replace('  ', ' ')  # double space to single
    # verify there's only two values in the line
    if (len(row.split(' ')) == 2):
        code, value = row.split(' ')
        if (len(code) == 3 and
            code[0] in 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz' and 
            code[1].isdigit() and 
            code[2].isdigit()):
            try:
                float_val = float(value)
                # looks like we have valid input, tally the value
                if (code in code_sums):
                    code_sums[code] += float_val
                else:
                    code_sums[code] = float_val
            except:
                pass # probably a malformed input line

#for code in code_sums.keys():
#    print("%s -> %7.1f" % (code, code_sums[code]))

fout = open("output_file.csv", "wt")  # TODO - handle errors
fout.write("Code,Sum\n")
for code in code_sums.keys():
    fout.write("%s,%7.1f\n" % (code, code_sums[code]))
fout.close()
```

Comment: Instead of printing the output, could I have it output to a .csv? With each line having "a11, 0" etc. `with open('output.txt', 'a') as the_file:
    the_file.write(code, code_sums[code])` doesn't work :( Otherwise this is great!

Comment: @Liquidity - there you go.